# A water heater pressure relief valve/pipe is guided to release hot water outside of the pan (see picture). Is this installation correct?

Tags: water-heater, hot-water

A plumber installed the hot water pressure relief pipe to point outside the water heater pan, as shown in this picture (on the right). What could be the reason to do so? Is this recommended/proper installation? Why not **in** the pan?
[image]

Comment: Seems like a great way to rot the floor ...

Comment: So what was the plumber’s name? Dilbert or Bob (the builder)?

Comment: It was installed in 2011, so too late to ask questions :(. The plumber replaced the water heater and installed this new pan. I'm asking just now since another plumber looked and had no clue why it was done this way.

Comment: The pipe from the TPV should go either outside the structure or into a drain. Is there an opening into the sewer near the water heater? The pan is also supposed to have an attached drain to conduct any water away. If there is no practical route for this you could put a water sensor in the drain pan and connect it to an audible alarm.

Comment: yes, there is drain at the back of the pan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd cut it off just above the first elbow. If there's a drain in the back of the pan it can empty out there. Not perfect, but better than what you got now.

The end of the relief pipe is supposed to come down to within 6" of the floor, but it looks like that's about where it would be.